# How can I align statements in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

how can I align statements as follows:

```
    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    button    = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

instead of

```
    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

in Android Studio?

Comment: I would suggest you to use DataBinding as it would help you to reduce your lines of code and even help you to avoid null pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for Java, should probably work for Kotlin too.

> Go to File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Group Declarations > (check Align Fields in columns)

[image]